# Google Apps for Salesforce -Gmail

Tags: google-apps

I am trying to set up Google Apps for Salesforce. I have entered all the relevant information in the Settings menu in Salesforce, so now I can see a Send Gmail button in the activity history on my contacts detail page. I can click on the button and it redirects me to Gmail and auto-populates the bcc field. I can send an email and the contact will receive it. 
The only thing that doesn't work is attaching that email to the activity history. For some reason this does not work. Do I need to set up anything in addition?
Thanks,
Lily

Comment: Do you have Email to Salesforce turned on? Have the users entered their email addresses as permitted senders? CApps for Salesforce just uses the existing Email to Salesforce functionality.

Answer (score 1):

if this is still not working for you, have you checked your Unresolved items? If the email cannot be linked back to the record for some reason, it will be appear as an unresolved email and will show in your "My Tasks" section of the Home tab, waiting for you to attach it to the correct contact.  The reason that the email did not automatically link to the contact in the first place, is usually because the email address did not match, or was not unique to that contact.

hope this helps - 
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Hi Lily – Are you using standard object Activities?  If so, it should automatically show the email as a completed task of type email in the Activity History related list on the lead or contact record.

Comment: Unfortunately a sent email is not shown in the Activity History. The email is received by the contact, but for some reason is not attached.